# Add to cart script doesn't add the products to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I got this problem where I created the database table "cart" with p_id and ip_add for such. When I hove over the add to cart button it shows me the product_id from the database on the table products, but when I click the button it doesn't add them to the database. here's the script:

```
function cart(){

if(isset($_GET['add_cart'])){

    $pro_id = $_GET['add_cart'];

    global $con; 

    $ip = getIp();

    $check_pro = "select * from cart where p_id='$pro_id' AND ip_add='$ip'";

    $run_check = mysqli_query($con, $check_pro); 

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_check)>0){

    echo "";

    }
    else {

        $insert_prod = "insert into cart (p_id,ip_add) values ('$pro_id','$ip')";

        $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_prod); 

        if($run_pro) {
            echo "<script>alert('Product added to the cart')</script>";

            echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
        } else {
            echo "Product failed to be added";
        }
    }

}

}
```

so far I get the "Product failed to be added".. on the Index.php so I didn't forget to add the function on the index.

Here's the code where I get the add_cart value, on the last link inside the div tags:

```
function getPro(){

    if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){
        if(!isset($_GET['brand'])){

    global $con; 

    $get_pro = "select * from products order by RAND() LIMIT 0,6";

    $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro); 

    while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){

        $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
        $pro_cat = $row_pro['product_cat'];
        $pro_brand = $row_pro['product_brand'];
        $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
        $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
        $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];

        echo "
                <div id='single_product'>

                    <h3>$pro_title</h3>

                    <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='180' height='180' />

                    <p><b> Price: $ $pro_price </b></p>

                    <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>Details</a>

                    <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button style='float:right'>Add to Cart</button></a>

                </div>


        ";

    }
    }
}

}
```

Safe to say:
1. that the getIp() worked really great being this file on the server and it showed my public ip when I tested it. 
2. The script is connected to the database and so far no errors connecting there.
3. The table is called cart and has the structure of p_id, ip_add and qty.

Any help will be really thanked.

Comment: Side note, you probably don't want to use the ip of the client as an identifier. You may run into issues where a client is using  a VPN with a shared IP address so multiple users will be using this address. If multiple users have the same ip, they will technically be able to tap into the same cart. You may want to use a session or a cookie to track the cart.

Comment: Also, you don't want to do this: `"select * from cart where p_id='$pro_id' AND ip_add='$ip'"`, it is prone to sql injection from the `$_GET` value(s).

Comment: You should see if you get a `mysqli` error on the insert. If there is an error it may help you figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for the advise @Rasclatt this is my first project on php and i'm following the course exactly to avoid bugs, but I'll keep those advises for later projects. So far no problem connecting to the database because the products are shown in the index.php from the database itself and when I hover over them it shows me the /XX.XX.XXX.XXX/ecommerce/index.php?add_cart=21 on the bottom left of the page, being 21 that specific product id from the products table.